# According to Rashi by Avraham's prayer for Sodom he reasoned that there were 8 righteous being saved. How would Ham be considered righteous?

Tags: tanach, rashi, abraham

According to [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.18.32.1?lang=bi) on Genesis 18:32, Abraham reasoned that 8 righteous people weren't enough to save the world so that's the limit. However given what we know about Ham (cited [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.108b.15?with=all&lang=bi) and other places), how could Avraham believe that there were 8 righteous people? Is he giving Ham the benefit of the doubt?

Comment: So I did find an Etz Yosef on the Midrash that Rashi quoted that seemingly answers my question by saying: כבר נשתייר בדור המבול כו'. היינו נח ושלשה בניו ונשותיהם ואע"ג דחם רשע היה מ"מ לא נחשד על הגזל ועל החמס שבעבורו נחתם עיקר הגז"ד (נזה"ק):

Comment: However there is a [Maharsha](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Niddah.61b.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) that says Cham's wife did some quite inappropriate things. Is it appropriate to say per the Etz Yosef cited above that although these behaviors are quite heinous since it doesn't necessarily fall under the umbrella of what the final decision for the ruling was for the destruction, than she would still be loosely defined as "righteous"?

Comment: Noach didn't save his generation. Only him and his family were rescued. Avraham was asking if there were enough tzadikim to save the entire city, not just themselves.

Comment: Rashi explicitly says (link above) there were 8 righteous people during the Dar Hamabul which would include Cham and his wife.